# Can i add an event programmatically in the user phone calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, laravel-4

I am creating a mobile version of a website with Laravel 4 framework (i'm using jquery normal not jquery mobile), I want to know if I can with code (javascript - jquery ... a plugin) added an event in the calendar of the user's phone .. thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an module in javascript to create ics file :
https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js 
Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn’t require JavaScript. Just generate an [ICS file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) of your event and link to it.

On iOS, tapping on such a link will show the event details and allow to add it to the calendar. I haven’t tried on Android and Windows Mobile but I’m pretty sure they deal with this in a similar way.